# probability of arrangement of books on a shelf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Qn:

You have s books on algebra, f on probability and v on calculus. The
books are all different. If you place them on a shelf at random what is the
probability that
Books on the same subject are adjacent.

i got answer ,

Comment: Any help?? I am not sure how to work on it..

Answer (score 1):

There are $s!$ ways of arranging algebra books (the number of possible permutations - see [here](http://www.statlect.com/comper1.htm)), $f!$ ways of arranging probability books and $v!$ ways of arranging calculus books, plus $3!$ ways of arranging the three groups.
So, the number of favorable outcomes is: $s!\;f!\;v!\;3!$
The total number of possible outcomes is $(s+f+v)!$
The probability is equal to the ratio of favorable outcomes to possible outcomes:

$$\frac{s!\; f!\;v!\; 3!}{(s+f+v)!}$$